# Get previously selected value or prevent default on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

Is it possible on `<select>` get previously selected value or prevent default somehow? For example i have

```
<select id="select_site" name="sites" selectedindex="0">
<option value="">Please select site</option>
<option value="4">first</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">second</option>
<option value="8">third</option>
</select>
```

So if selected option with null value i need to restore previously selected `second` value.

Comment: You can keep track of the previously selected value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a change event handler to the element and store the new value in a variable. If the value is an empty string, set it to whatever is in the variable:

```
$('#select_site').change(function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = $(this).data('previous_value');
    }
    else {
        $(this).data('previous_value', this.value);
    }
}).triggerHandler('change'); // <- trigger change event to get initial value
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/65ctQ/)

Answer (score 1):

no js needed:

```
<select id="select_site" name="sites" selectedindex="0">
  <optgroup label="Please select site">
    <option value="4">first</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">second</option>
    <option value="8">third</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/obeker/1/

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: one more - IF SELECTED VALUE IS NULL, I NEED TO RETURN PREVIOUS VALUE!

Comment: @Kirix 1) no need to yell, 2) you can't select `null` with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that because the change event is fired after the select is focused out, not before the selection is changed. There is no native *"onbeforechange"* event but you can remove the empty value once the selection is changed so it is no longer available.

Code to do this:

```
$('select').change(function (event) {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() !== '') {
        $this.children('option:first').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: but how to detect witch value was before?

Comment: @Kirix You cannot unless you store in javascript the previous value.

Comment: i do not need to remove value, i need just to return to the previous one